# Toggle between the icons Font Awesome

Tags: javascript, vue.js, toggle, font-awesome

I am using two Font awesome icons in same button in Vuejs. Now what I want to do is to change the icons upon click and toggle back if clicked again. The HTML code is:

```
<b-button @click="myFunction(this)" id="toggle_icon" class="action-button" v-b-tooltip.hover title="Cells Comparison">
  <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas','car-battery']"/> &nbsp;
  <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas','balance-scale']"/>                            
</b-button>
```

The JS function is:

```
    function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("fa-thumbs-down");
}
```

I am getting the error "myFunction' is defined but never used". No JQuery

Answer (score 1):

You can use computed property for this.

1. Make a data property named carbattery or toggle or whatever you feel describes it the most.
2. Make a computed property that returns the font awesome icon depending on the carbattery/toggle
3. bind the computed property

Something like this:

```
data () {
  return {
    carbattery: true
  }
},
computed: {
  icon() {
    if (this.carbattery) {
      return ['fas','car-battery']
    } else {
      return ['fas','balance-scale']
    }
  }
}

<b-button @click="carbattery = !carbattery" class="action-button" v-b-tooltip.hover title="Cells Comparison">
  <font-awesome-icon :icon="icon"/>
</b-button>
```

Comment: Just a little improvement in computed property: ```return ['fas', this.cabattery ? 'car-battery', 'balance-scale']```

Comment: Yeah, this is a nice one-liner,  but for a beginner it's also harder to read.

Comment: where exactly to add data(), in attached picture? https://files.fm/u/r6nrk2tu8

Comment: You have the data function, just add carbattery: true in line 177 (and add comma at the end of line 176)

Comment: Add a comma at the end of line 69, hence the error message: expected ", "